# mascara AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, mask-plugin

Estou utilizando `AngularJS` e em meu formulário tenho alguns campos que necessitam de mascaras, até aí já consegui fazer, utilizei o `ui.mask`.

```
var app = angular.module("empresaApp",['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','ui.mask']);
```

meu input ficou assim:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="empresa.nr_CNPJ" ui-mask="99.999.999/9999-99"  />
```

Porem quando vou inserir os dados, nesse campo por exemplo fica **22222222222222** e não aplica a mascara, alguém já teve problema com isso ou sabe como resolver isso. Preciso salvar no banco de dados já com a mascara?

Comment: Importou a biblioteca? deu algum erro no console? empresa.nr_CNPJ está definido no controller?

Comment: Sim, importei a biblioteca, não deu erro no console e o campo empresa.nr_CNPJ está definido sim

Comment: Em qual momento isso acontece?, tipo é na hora de atribuir valores na `nr_CNPJ`?

Comment: eu penas necessito que ao cadastrar no banco, ele informe com a mascara, daí que achei que apenas atribuindo essa mascara, o valor iria ser enviado ao banco com a mascara

Comment: A solução proposta por mim ajuda?

Comment: na verdade não, continua enviando dados ao banco sem a mascara

Comment: Rapaz mande o código inteiro seu! deixa eu ver? eu fiz o exemplo ta mostrando a sua maneira, então tem algo errado no código!

Comment: eu resolvi forçando o envio pelo model

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, a máscara exibe o valor somente no campo de texto, é necessário formata-lo antes de gravar no banco. O ideal é gravar o valor sem formatação nenhuma, e tratando-se de um CNPJ a melhor opção é o tipo de dado numérico (facilita busca, performance e outras coisas).

Caso realmente seja necessário gravar uma string formatada, vc deve forma-la antes de chegar ao BD.

Você pode fazer isso no backend (se utiliza Java por exemplo), pode fazer isso no JavaScript antes de chegar ao backend. Para fazer em Javascript (Angular), faça através de Regex:

```
$scope.formatCnpj = function(cnpj) {
   return cnpj.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{2})/, "$1.$2.$3/$4-$5");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No [ui-mask](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask) o formato dos dados fica somente no elemento que no caso é um `<input>`, no model é o dado sem formatação, mas, existe uma forma para recuperar o valor formatado:

```
angular.element('#id_do_elemento').val()
```

com [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) vem o valor com a mascara, olha um ***exemplo minimo***:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.mask']);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.text = "11111111111111";
  $scope.read = function() 
  {    
    console.log(angular.element('#text').val());    
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-mask/1.8.7/mask.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input id="text" type="text" ng-model="text" ui-mask="99.999.999/9999-99" ui-mask-placeholder-char="_" />
  <button ng-click="read()">Log</button>
</div>
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [ui-mask](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask)
- [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)